# Angular Observable.startWith Causes Binding Check Error

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm working on building custom controls for an HTML5 audio player in Angular, and I am creating an Observable from an event like this:

```
this.$trackLength = Observable.fromEvent(this.audioPlayer.nativeElement, 'canplaythrough')
```

I then add a `.map` to get the value that I want, and that works great. But I want to initialize the `Observable` with a 0 so that it doesn't show up as blank or null when the component loads. So I found `startWith` which does just that. So in the end, the Observable looks like this:

```
this.$trackLength = Observable.fromEvent(this.audioPlayer.nativeElement, 'canplaythrough')
    .map(() => Math.ceil(this.audioPlayer.nativeElement.duration))
    .startWith(0);
```

It seems like that should work, and it kind of does, but I get an error in the console:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at checkBindingNoChanges (core.js:9912)
    at checkNoChangesNodeInline (core.js:13961)
    at checkNoChangesNode (core.js:13935)
    at debugCheckNoChangesNode (core.js:14764)
    at debugCheckRenderNodeFn (core.js:14704)
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (AudioPlayerComponent.html:21)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:14686)
    at checkNoChangesView (core.js:13775)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14126)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14078)
```

I'm fairly confident it's something to do with the `startWith` addition, because as soon as I take that part off, the error disappears.

I don't know what the error is or how to fix it. Thanks in advance for any suggestions or help.

### Edit

[Here's a link](https://github.com/pjlamb12/angular-html5-audio/tree/abbda87f8b3ca7cfbbe55cdd074fc52e6c073c50/src/app/audio-player/audio-player) that goes to the folder with the component files in it, on the correct branch in my GitHub repo.

Comment: Show also your code part, where you use `name` property

Comment: That's another thing, I'm not using any object with an attribute of name at all. It's part of why I don't understand where this error is even coming from.

Comment: It's very unlikely this is related to `startWith` because it just initializes the Observable with `0`. The error is thrown by Angular because in `AudioPlayerComponent.html` on `21` line you have a wrong template binding.

Comment: @martin if you look at the actual HTML file, and not just the error, you'll see that I don't have a template binding on line 21 there. That's where a lot of my confusion came from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing your repository, I'm getting a different error message, which starts with the following.

> Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'null'. Current value: '0'.

Essentially, the variables `this.$trackLength`, `this.$currentTimeDisplay` & `this.$playheadPosition` start off null and remain so until ngAfterViewInit() fires, then you define a pipeline for them and prime it with '0' - all within one change cycle.

I was able to fix it by 'bumping' the `startsWith(0)` into the next change detection cycle, by adding `delay(0)` to the end.

**Note** that `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` is more of a warning and is only shown in development mode, but it doesn't necessarily mean the error goes away in production mode. But in your code, this is not really an error - the change detection checking is just being over-zealous.

```js
initEvents() {
  this.$trackLength = Observable.fromEvent(this.audioPlayer.nativeElement, 'canplaythrough')
    .map(() => {
      this.isReadyForPlayback = true;
      return Math.ceil(this.audioPlayer.nativeElement.duration);
    })
    .startWith(0).delay(0);

  this.$currentTimeDisplay = Observable.fromEvent(this.audioPlayer.nativeElement, 'timeupdate')
    .map(() => {
      const current = this.audioPlayer.nativeElement.currentTime;
      const duration = this.audioPlayer.nativeElement.duration;
      if (current === duration) {
        return 0;
      }
      return Math.ceil(current);
    })
    .startWith(0).delay(0);

  this.$playheadPosition = Observable.fromEvent(this.audioPlayer.nativeElement, 'timeupdate')
    .map(() => {
      const percentAsDecimal =
        this.audioPlayer.nativeElement.currentTime / this.audioPlayer.nativeElement.duration;
      if (percentAsDecimal >= 1) {
        this.isPlaying = false;
        return 0;
      }
      return 100 * percentAsDecimal;
    })
    .startWith(0).delay(0);
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.initEvents();
}
```

**Demo**  [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jhka6s?file=app%2Faudio-player%2Faudio-player%2Faudio-player.component.ts)
Note, StackBlitz in Chrome does not preview in the same tab. You need to use 'Open in new window'.

---

Also the `<audio #audioPlayer` should not use `*ngIf`, use `[hidden]` instead.

At the moment, your app.component always passes in a valid `audioSrc` but if audioSrc becomes invalid, you get an error.

```html
<audio #audioPlayer *ngIf="audioSrc" [src]="audioSrc"></audio>  

<audio #audioPlayer [hidden]="!audioSrc" [src]="audioSrc"></audio>  // use [hidden] instead
```

since this relies on finding it in the DOM

```js
@ViewChild('audioPlayer') audioPlayer: ElementRef;
```

Comment: Is the `*ngIf` what causes `this.audioPlayer` to be null in `ngOnInit`? I tried putting the Observable definitions in `ngOnInit` but got an error; that's why they're in `ngAfterViewInit`.

Comment: Sorry I did this late last night and was too focused on `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`. I'll work on it a bit more and revise the answer, but essentially you are correct in that `this.audioPlayer` is null in OnInit so must be accessed in AfterViewInit. (Not caused by the *ngIf, at least not as the code currently stands, because audioSrc is hard-coded so *ngIf is always true.)

Comment: I think the trick might be to 'bump' the `startsWith` out of the first change cycle with something like `delay(0)`

Comment: I finally was able to test this. and by using the `[hidden]` directive instead, I could move everything to the `ngOnInit` function and use `.startWith` without a `.delay`. Thanks for your help!